# How can I add customised header on http request for authentication when using flutter graphql library?

Tags: flutter, graphql

I am using this library https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter for graphql in a flutter web application.  Below code can be used to get authentication token:

```
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';
final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
    'https://api.github.com/graphql',
  );

  final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
    getToken: () async => 'Bearer <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
    // OR
    // getToken: () => 'Bearer <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
  );
```

but how can I put the token in the http header like `x-api-key: xxxx` when sending requests?

I have tried:

```dart
HttpLink link = HttpLink(
    uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'x-api-key': 'xxxx',
    },
  );
```

but it gives me the error: `The named parameter 'uri' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'uri'.`

Answer (score 2):

Base on the answer from @moaid-alrazhy and after checking how AuthLink is working

```dart
class CustomAuthLink extends Link {
  CustomAuthLink();

  @override
  Stream<Response> request(Request request, [NextLink? forward]) async* {
    // Some logic here
    final AuthService authService = GetIt.I.get<AuthService>();

    final String? token = authService.token;
    final String deviceID = await DeviceInformation.deviceIMEINumber;

    // TIP: do not forget getting new Request instance!
    final Request req = request.updateContextEntry<HttpLinkHeaders>(
      (HttpLinkHeaders? headers) => HttpLinkHeaders(
        headers: <String, String>{
          // put oldest headers
          ...headers?.headers ?? <String, String>{},
          // and add a new headers
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          'x-device-id': deviceID,
        },
      ),
    );

    // and "return" new Request with updated headers
    yield* forward!(req);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: base on the answer from @Moaid

```dart
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';

typedef GetHeaders = FutureOr<Map<String, String>> Function();

class CustomAuthLink extends Link {
  CustomAuthLink({
    this.getHeaders,
  });

  final GetHeaders getHeaders;

  @override
  Stream<Response> request(Request request, [NextLink forward]) {
    StreamController<Response> controller;
    Future<void> onListen() async {
      try {
        final Map<String, String> headers = await getHeaders();

        return request.updateContextEntry<HttpLinkHeaders>(
          (_headers) => HttpLinkHeaders(
            headers: <String, String>{
              ...headers,
            },
          ),
        );
      } catch (error) {
        controller.addError(error);
      }

      await controller.addStream(forward(request));
      await controller.close();
    }

    controller = StreamController<Response>(onListen: onListen);

    return controller.stream;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you need to change only the name of the Authentication value you can edit the headerKey param
[image]

otherwise other parameters can be insert in the "defaultHeaders" fields of the HttpLink object. but I don't know if they can be use for authentication

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can add it to your HttpLink  like this

```
HttpLink link = HttpLink(
    'https://api.github.com/graphql',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'x-api-key': 'xxxx',
    },
  );
```

however this was in old versions .. now for more headers your have to write your own CustomAuthLink like

```
typedef GetHeaders = Future<Map<String, String>> Function();

class CustomAuthLink extends Link {
  CustomAuthLink({
    this.getHeaders,
  }) : super(
          request: (Operation operation, [NextLink forward]) {
            StreamController<FetchResult> controller;

            Future<void> onListen() async {
              try {
                final Map<String, String> headers = await getHeaders();

                operation.setContext(<String, Map<String, String>>{
                  'headers': headers
                });
              } catch (error) {
                controller.addError(error);
              }

              await controller.addStream(forward(operation));
              await controller.close();
            }

            controller = StreamController<FetchResult>(onListen: onListen);

            return controller.stream;
          },
        );

  GetHeaders getHeaders;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but it gives me compile error: `The named parameter 'uri' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'uri'.`

Comment: just remove it , seems they update it.

I've update the answer check it.

Comment: same error happens on header: `The named parameter 'headers' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'headers'.`. Where do you get the API doc for this library?

Comment: I got this error if I remove `headers`, `Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.`.

Comment: sorrt the syntax I gave you was in version 1.0.0+1 which indeed had the ma,ed parameters uri and headers
about the last one you can check it here 
https://pub.dev/documentation/graphql_flutter/latest/